# Permissions for Jenkins to allow post-receive hooks, yet block anonymous users

Tags: git, jenkins

I'm trying to disable Anonymous access to our Jenkins installation, but still allow Codebase Git to perform post-receive hooks to post to Jenkins, to allow it to trigger a build.

We're using Matrix-based security, and have allowed only the following permissions for Anonymous users:

- Overall > Read
- Job > Read
- Job > Build

These are the minimum I have to activate in order to get Codebase posting the URL, otherwise I get access denied errors from Jenkins, the problem is, it allows anonymous users to browse our   projects?

Is there a way to obscure this? I think it's really stupid that Jenkins needs **Overall > Read** access to allow the **Job > Build** permission to work.

Answer (score 1):

This is how we do:

You can make a new user called github for an example  and give it the same three permissions, then when you link to the build url you include the username and password in the url, like:

```
http://USER:PASS@jenkins_url/job/JOBNAME/build
```

This way you do not allow anonymous user access your Jenkins instance.

Comment: There's apparently now an API token that prevents you from having to reveal your real password.  To quote from their site, "Specifying the real password is still supported after 1.426, but it is not recommended because the risk of revealing password, and the human tendency to reuse the same password in different places."  https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Authenticating+scripted+clients

Comment: Yes, that is right, but you would create a user with the minimal access abilities, and hopefully with a unique password, when you want to use webhooks.
But a good idea if you want to use your own account :)